# The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectmapper, mapper

I have this in my code:

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> objectMap = oMapper.convertValue(test, Map.class);
```

And i receive the following warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Object>
```

How can i solve this?

**SOLUTION:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> objectMap = oMapper.convertValue(prueba, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

Comment: Isn't it better to have a warning than executing a new on every method call?